# VSCode keyboard shortcut to go to split windows using the side numeric keypad (and/or top number bar)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use the keyboard to go from split window 1 to 2 to 3 etc.

I know I can press `command+1`, `command+2`, `command+3` using the numbers at the top of the keyboard.

But his only works for number bar on top, it does **not** work with the **number pad**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This ended up not being a real issue, I believe I was in a context where those keys were not working, but when I reopened a different project, the issue was gone, so either an extension was causing my issue or some other environment issue.

Answer (score 3):

These keys are accepted:

```
numpad0-numpad9, numpad_multiply, numpad_add, numpad_separator
numpad_subtract, numpad_decimal, numpad_divide
```

So you would need to make your keybindings with those keys:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+numpad0",
  "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

You may be able to do this simply with the context menu command `Add Keybinding...` on each of the commands, like `workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1` you find in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` list.  And then use your numpad keys and see what it adds to your `keybindings.json` file.

see [keybindings - accepted keys](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_accepted-keys)